# Postgresql: count entries by another column

Tags: psql

In Postgresql,  if you have a table that has two columns: a list of purchases, and another column that is the state in which those purchases were made, how would you count the number of purchases by state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your column names are `state` and `purchases` you can group by the `state` column and use `count(purchases)` to count all the instances of purchases within that state.  I have posted an example below.  You will just need to fill in the table name that you are pulling from.

```
SELECT 
    state, 
    count(purchases) as purchase_count
FROM
    [table_name]
GROUP BY
    state
```

Secondarily, you can order the with the most purchases to the least by using `ORDER BY` and referencing the column number.  Example below:

```
SELECT 
    state, 
    count(purchases) as purchase_count
FROM
    [table_name]
GROUP BY
    state
ORDER BY
    2 DESC
```